# Formatting arrays specifically in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have the following PHP code on my website:

```
<?php
    $FirstName = array("Jacob", "Noah", "Frank");
    $LastName = array("Collins", "Little", "Allen");
    $BirthDay = array(19, 31, 06);
?>
```

And I want it to be output like so:

```
("Jacob", "Collins", 19), ("Noah", "Little", 31), ("Frank", "Allen", 06)
```

for an SQL string, which will be:

```
INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, BirthDay) VALUES ("Jacob", "Collins", 19), ("Noah", "Little", 31), ("Frank", "Allen", 06);
```

I am quite new to PHP (only started yesterday) and was wondering how I would do this.

Thanks.

Comment: will be the count of all the array will be same

Comment: You chould separate brackets with commas too: `(...),  (...)`

Comment: Each filed is required (FirstName, LastName, BirthDay), so the first element of each array will match, so it wont end up somehow being `("Noah", "Collins", 06)`

Comment: From what i gather, you are trying to build an INSERT query by concatenating strings. even if you are just new to php or programming itself, plase understand that this is DANGEROUS! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) please look into parameterised queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, If you have same count of  `$FirstName`, `$LastName` and `$BirthDay`,

using `for` loop and `array_push` you can do it like this:

```
$data = array();
$count = count($FirstName);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){

    $insert = [$FirstName[$i],$LastName[$i], $BirthDay[$i]];
    array_push($data,$insert);

}
```

The `$data` gives you formatted array.

Comment: How would I echo `$data`?

Comment: use function like `print_r()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just new to PHP, let's not yet get into classes.

An easy way to do this, without destroying or modifying the data you are storing is by using a multidimensional array, like this :

```
$myArray = array(
  array( "Jacob", "Collins", 19 ),
  array( "Noah", "Little", 31 )
);

// Displays "Noah little 31"
echo $myArray[1][0]." ".$myArray[1][1]." ".$myArray[1][2];

foreach ($myArray as $row)
{
    //concatenate this to your query string.
    $assembledQuery = "(\"$row[0]\", \"$row[1]\", $row[2])";
}
```

However, PLEASE keep in mind that this way of building queries is VERY VERY dangerous!

Answer (score 0):

you can do using for loops

```
<?php
$FirstName = array("Jacob", "Noah", "Frank");
    $LastName = array("Collins", "Little", "Allen");
    $BirthDay = array(19, 31, 06);
$length = count($FirstName);
for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++)
{
    $custom = array();
    $f = $FirstName[$x];
    $l = $LastName[$x];
    $b = $BirthDay[$x];
    array_push($custom,$f);
    array_push($custom,$l);
    array_push($custom,$b);
    print_r($custom);
}
?>
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: if the count is same you can use above method @JacobCollins

Answer (score 0):

below code is help you when birthday or lastname is not in array

```
    $data = [];
    $total = count($FirstName);
    for($i = 0;$i < $total;$i++) {
        $tmp = [];
        $tmp[] = (isset($FirstName[$i]))? $FirstName[$i] : "";
        $tmp[] = (isset($LastName[$i]))? $LastName[$i] : "";
        $tmp[] = (isset($BirthDay[$i]))? $BirthDay[$i] : "";
        $data[] = $tmp;
    }

    // $data is array what you want i have just dump the $data 

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
```